# Is there a way to copy BLOB records between databases in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, blob

We have a production table that has millions of rows in it and contains a BLOB field, I would like to copy a smaller selection of these records into our development database without getting a DBA involved if possible.  I tried the following COPY command but received a `CPY-0012: Datatype cannot be copied`

```
COPY FROM user/password@prod_db TO user/password@dev_db -
INSERT TABLE_A (COL1, COL2, COL3, BLOB_COL) USING -
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, BLOB_COL -
FROM TABLE_A WHERE COL1='KEY'
```

Is there a way to copy records with a BLOB field between databases via SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot copy `BLOB` values using the `COPY` command.

An alternative is to set up a DB link on the source database, and execute a `SQL INSERT` statement:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK link_to_prod CONNECT TO prod_user IDENTIFIED BY prod_password USING 'prod_db';

INSERT INTO TABLE_A@link_to_prod (COL1, COL2, COL3, BLOB_COL) SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, BLOB_COL FROM TABLE_A
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a bummer.  Due to internal auditing I'm not 'permitted' to create a DB link from one database to another, especially from production to another location.  Looks like I need to get a DBA involved no matter what.

Answer (score 4):

[Oracle's Data Pump (started 10g+)](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/OracleDataPump10g.php) supports moving BLOB data.

Comment: Data Pump still requires a DB link to be created and specified with the network_link parameter if the copy needs to happen between servers.

Comment: @Datajam Ltd: Yes, I believe the link provided addresses that - what's your point?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution I like--this version has a 4000 character limitation on the CLOB.

1) on the COPY TO database:

```
create TABLE_A_TMP as 
select COL1, COL2, COL3, cast(BLOB_COL as varchar2(4000)) BLOB_COL
from TABLE_A
where 1=0;
```

2) then run the copy command

```
COPY FROM user/password@prod_db TO user/password@dev_db -
 INSERT TABLE_A_TMP (COL1, COL2, COL3, BLOB_COL) USING -
 SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, cast(BLOB_COL as varchar2(4000)) -
 FROM TABLE_A WHERE COL1='KEY'
```

3) on the COPY TO database:

```
INSERT TABLE_A (COL1, COL2, COL3, BLOB_COL)
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, BLOB_COL
FROM TABLE_A_TMP
```

4) then drop the tmp table

I had been struggling with this limitation, and this solution has helped me alot.

Comment: Do you ever has scenarios where you need more than 4000 characters?  I like this idea, but in my case the blob field can be quite large.