# Oracle copy blob data from one table to another

Tags: copy, oracle10g, rows

I have a table (over 1.000.000 rows and 60GB data) with a blob column. I want to move most of the rows (not all rows) of the table to another table. I tried `insert into X select from y` command but it is too slow.

**What is the fastest way?**

I have Oracle 10 or 11.

Comment: You might want to pose your question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @ismail - Can you define "too slow"?  How long does it take to copy 60 GB of data?  How long do you need it to take?  What are the wait events?  Does 60 GB comprise the size of the table segment?  Or the LOB segment?  Or the combined size of both segments?

Comment: it is take full night (18:00-08:00) to copy is it normall?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to copy BLOB records between databases in Oracle 10g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022706/is-there-a-way-to-copy-blob-records-between-databases-in-oracle-10g)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use /*+ append */ hint to pass archive log
when you use the hint oracle dosent create arcive logs

```
insert  /*+ append */ into TABLE1
select  *
from    TABLE2
```

Answer (score 1):

its too late to suggest something, but it may help with above solutions, if your new(target) table has constraints or indexes or triggers, then try to remove/disable them first, then load your bulk of data and finally create/enable your constraints, indexes and triggers back and analyze your table indexes. this time saving solution is only suggested when you only have to replicate your bulk data once. as while inserting new records in table DBMS ensures the constraints, checks and indexes which reduces the speed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we don't know your system so it's hard to tell you much. Your question really depends on your environment. Regardless, here are some tests anyways to show the time and resources it takes to use your method versus another method:

Let's say your method is method 1 and the other method is method 2.

```
20:43:24 SQL> set autotrace on;
20:43:30 SQL> alter session set SQL_TRACE=TRUE;

Session altered.

20:43:39 SQL> --let's make sure we are reading from disk (for arguments sake)
20:43:45 SQL> alter system flush shared_pool;

System altered.

20:43:45 SQL> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.

20:43:45 SQL> 
20:43:45 SQL> --clear my examples
20:43:45 SQL> drop table t;
drop table t
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


20:43:49 SQL> drop table u;
drop table u
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


20:43:49 SQL> 
20:43:49 SQL> --create table u - we will populate this with random numbers
20:43:49 SQL> create table u (y varchar2(4000));

Table created.

20:43:50 SQL> 
20:43:50 SQL> --insert 1 million rows of random numbers
20:43:50 SQL> insert into u
20:43:50   2  (select dbms_random.normal
20:43:50   3  from dual
20:43:50   4  CONNECT BY level <= 1000000);

1000000 rows created.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1236776825

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT              |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL      | U    |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|      |       |            |          |
|   3 |    FAST DUAL                  |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(LEVEL<=1000000)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
       4175  recursive calls
      58051  db block gets
      13118  consistent gets
         47  physical reads
   54277624  redo size
        675  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        647  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
         56  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
    1000000  rows processed

20:44:21 SQL> 
20:44:21 SQL> --create table t - we will populate this from table u
20:44:21 SQL> create table t (x varchar2(4000));

Table created.

20:44:21 SQL> 
20:44:21 SQL> --let's make sure we are reading from disk (for arguments sake)
20:44:21 SQL> alter system flush shared_pool;

System altered.

20:44:21 SQL> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.

20:44:26 SQL> 
20:44:26 SQL> --insert data from u to t (this is how you said you did this)
20:44:26 SQL> insert into t (select * from u);

1000000 rows created.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 537870620

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |      |   997K|  1905M|  1750   (1)| 00:00:21 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | T    |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL      | U    |   997K|  1905M|  1750   (1)| 00:00:21 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
       5853  recursive calls
      58201  db block gets
      24213  consistent gets
       6551  physical reads
   54591764  redo size
        681  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        599  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
         57  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
    1000000  rows processed

20:44:41 SQL> 
20:44:41 SQL> 
20:44:41 SQL> --now let's start over with a different method
20:44:41 SQL> drop table t;

Table dropped.

20:44:48 SQL> drop table u;

Table dropped.

20:44:50 SQL> 
20:44:50 SQL> --create table u - we will populate this with random numbers
20:44:50 SQL> create table u (y varchar2(4000));

Table created.

20:44:51 SQL> 
20:44:51 SQL> --insert 1 million rows of random numbers
20:44:51 SQL> insert into u
20:44:51   2  (select dbms_random.normal
20:44:51   3  from dual
20:44:51   4  CONNECT BY level <= 1000000);

1000000 rows created.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1236776825

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT              |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL      | U    |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|      |       |            |          |
|   3 |    FAST DUAL                  |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(LEVEL<=1000000)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
       2908  recursive calls
      58153  db block gets
      12831  consistent gets
         10  physical reads
   54284104  redo size
        683  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        647  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
         31  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
    1000000  rows processed

20:45:20 SQL> 
20:45:20 SQL> --let's make sure we are reading from disk (for arguments sake)
20:45:20 SQL> alter system flush shared_pool;

System altered.

20:45:20 SQL> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.

20:45:25 SQL> 
20:45:25 SQL> --create table t using table u
20:45:25 SQL> create table t as (select * from u);

Table created.

20:45:36 SQL> 
20:45:36 SQL> drop table t;

Table dropped.

20:45:41 SQL> drop table u;

Table dropped.

20:45:41 SQL> 
20:45:41 SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

20:45:41 SQL> spool off
```

Ok, so we care about the two methods we tested i.e.

```
insert into t (select * from u);
```

which we get an autotrace answer for and

```
create table t as (select * from u);
```

which we do not get an autotrace for.

Fortunately I also ran sql_trace and I picked up a TKprof of stats.

This is what I get:
for "insert into t (select * from u);":

```
********************************************************************************

SQL ID: bjdnhkhq8r6h4
Plan Hash: 537870620
insert into t (select * from u)



call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.03          2          2          0           0
Execute      1      1.74       7.67       6201      22538      58121     1000000
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        2      1.74       7.71       6203      22540      58121     1000000

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Misses in library cache during execute: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 91  

Rows     Row Source Operation
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      0  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      1   TABLE ACCESS FULL U (cr=4 pr=5 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1750 size=1997891896 card=997948)

********************************************************************************
```

and for "create table t as (select * from u)" we get:

```
********************************************************************************

SQL ID: asawpwvdj1nbv
Plan Hash: 2321469388
create table t as (select * from u)


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.03          2          2          1           0
Execute      1      0.90       2.68       6372      12823       8573     1000000
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        2      0.90       2.71       6374      12825       8574     1000000

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 91  

Rows     Row Source Operation
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      0  LOAD AS SELECT  (cr=13400 pr=6382 pw=6370 time=0 us)
1000000   TABLE ACCESS FULL U (cr=12640 pr=6370 pw=0 time=349545 us cost=1750 size=2159012856 card=1078428)

********************************************************************************
```

So what does this tell us?
well:
-Method 2 took about 65% less overall time than method 1 (a whole 5 seconds less for 1 million rows)
-Method 2 took about 48% less CPU time overall than method 1
-Slightly more disk was parsed with method 2 than method 1
-a lot less buffers were retrieved for method 2 than for method 1

hope this helps you :)